# FFMPEG - RTSP: where does sprop-parameter-sets come from?

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp

I'm encoding .mp4 video files (h265) with `ffmpeg` to create RTSP stream, put it to `rtsp-simple-server` and then after aler9's restreamer the stream is available to watch. I can watch the result in VLC (adding network source rtsp://my.server/stream), but can't watch the stream in Android application - no `sprop-parameter-sets` headers exist

So, the question is: where can I get these headers and how can I add them to the stream, so that everything worked?

P.S. if I add the stream to Wowza, these headers (`sprop-vps, sprop-sps, sprop-pps`) are added by Wowza to the stream, but I need to use the server directly.

Answer (score 0):

OK, found an answer: `'-bsf:v', 'dump_extra'`